# Cognito same email differente account. How is possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Let's say I have an username like teste01 with email teste@teste.com related to copany A.

Let's say this same user with same email is related do another company, B, so I would need to have an username teste02 with the same email teste@teste.com.

How to setup cognito to have this flow? same email in different accuont but with usernames diffetrent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in cognito if you enable username login. If you use "username" login and "allow email logins" then Cognito allows multiple accounts to have the same email address. For the purpose of logging in it will point to only one of those accounts (the verified one).