# How can I allow multiple AWS Cognito accounts to have the same email address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want a Cognito userpool where multiple accounts (i.e. usernames) can have the same email address.
I know this is generally considered a bad idea on multiple fronts but I am confident this is the solution I need.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972490/cognito-same-email-differente-account-how-is-possible) implies that this would work if I use "username" login and "allow email logins" but I have already set up my userpool this way and still get "UsernameExistsException: An account with the email already exists" upon attempting to sign up a new username/existing email.

The answer also implies that I will experience odd side-effects if I allow this, although I admit I don't know what "For the purpose of logging in it will point to only one of those accounts (the verified one)" means.

Is there another option?

Comment: Can't you just use `+` in emails like `my.name+1@domain.com`,  `my.name+2@domain.com` and `my.name+whatever@domain.com`??

Comment: Not all email providers support this

Answer (score 0):

Each user name must be unique. If you have a user pool where the user name ***is*** the e-mail address, then you cannot have users with the same e-mail address.

If you are using user names instead, then you can have users with the same e-mail address. In this case, the user name and e-mail address are distinct properties on the user. You could have:

```
User 1: 
name = Dad
e-mail = family@test.com

User 2: 
name = Mom
e-mail = family@test.com
```

If you are using e-mails as user names then they must be unique. If it suits your scenario (commonly for test users/accounts), there is a feature of most e-mail systems that you can use where you append a + and some text after the e-mail name. For example:

Given the account family@test.com all of the following addresses route to the same mailbox (and you don't need to configure anything with your mail provider):

- family+dad@test.com
- family+mom@test.com
- family+whateveryouwant@test.com

You can try this now by sending yourself an e-mail and confirming it goes to the same mailbox.

Comment: I don't want to use emails as usernames. I suspect the comment on the previous SO post had the config backwards.

Comment: In that case, it'll work fine. I just verified in my own AWS account. E-mail is just another attribute and doesn't require uniqueness. If I have answered your question, please upvote and mark it as the answer.